# How can I search for a element in unordered_set of pairs on the basis of first element>

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, unordered-set

```
unordered_set<pair<int, int> s;
```

I want to perform `s.find()` operation but I don't know how to implement it on the basis of first element.

`eg, if my set is: (3,4),(2,5),(5,6),(7,8)`

and I want to find 2nd element whose first element is 7 how can I do that.

Comment: Can you try to explain better? Why you want to find 7? is it because 3 + 4 = 7?

Comment: Are you trying to find the value of an entry whose key is 7? e.g. (3,4),(2,5),(5,6)(7,8)  -> 8?

Comment: @jh316 yes you are correct but I don't know how?

Comment: Will 1st element always be unique? If not, what is expected output in that case?

Comment: It will be unique always. Actually second value is frequency of first value and I wanted  to increase it.

Comment: @ReasonBehindTech I think `std::unordered_map<int, int>` is better than `unordered_set<pair<int, int> s;`, in this case

Answer (score 6):

```
 std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto& el){ return el.first == 7; })
```

or with C++20:

```
 std::ranges::find_if(s, [](auto& el){ return el.first == 7; })
```

(Both require `#include<algorithm>`.)

This will give back an iterator to an element containing `7` in the first position of the pair and `s.end()` if no such element was found.

However, this is cumbersome and has linear time complexity in the size of the container.
If you need to do this search often, you should probably use a

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>
```

or

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, int>
```

instead (depending on whether the first element may have the same value multiple times).

Then it is as easy as

```
s.find(7)
```

Comment: In the `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap`, how do you keep the `pair` relevant? Something is missing I'm sure or the syntax is wrong. I haven't coded in cpp in a while so I dont remember exactly, can you recheck your answer.

Comment: @vish4071 I am not sure what you mean. The `std::*map` types will also store pairs, though `std::pair<const int, int>` instead of `std::pair<int, int>`. So if OP needs direct access to them, that is no problem. I assume that they do not care about the `const`ness of the key.

Comment: Or are you changing the structure so `key` is 1st element and `value`  is second? Then it would make sense actually.

Comment: Yeah, I figured...nvm

Comment: Your answer is correct. See the comment from the OP above. The 2nd value of the pair is the frequency of the first. So, the idiomatic correct solution is the std::unordered_map (or std::map, if sorting is of interest). +1  plus should be accepted