# Search a pair in unordered_set of pairs from first element in C++

Tags: c++, find, std-pair, erase, unordered-set

I want to erase the pair: (x,"whatever"), and i want:
1)find an iterator position of the pair with x as first element
2)after that erase the element in the position of the iterator

```
typedef pair<int, int> pairs;

// Hash function
struct hashFunction{
   size_t operator()(const pairs &x) const{return x.first ^ x.second;}
};

//Comparator function
struct comp{
    bool operator()(pairs a , pairs b){     
        return a.first < b.first ? a : b;
    }
};

//The function that I want to implement
void delEdge(unordered_set<pairs>, hashFunction, comp> adj[], int u, int v){
    adj[v].erase(/*a function that finds the position of the pair (u,_)*/);
    adj[u].erase(/*a function that finds the position of the pair (v,_)*/);
}
```

I found that, it exists this function:

```
find_if(adj[v].begin(), adj[v].end(), [](auto& el){ return el.first == u; });
```

from: [How can I search for a element in unordered_set of pairs on the basis of first element>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459108/how-can-i-search-for-a-element-in-unordered-set-of-pairs-on-the-basis-of-first-e)

But as I have been searching, I found that this find_if complexity is O(n) and not O(1) on average.

Question:
How to implement: s.find(x), (s as an unordered_set of pairs) that finds the position of the (x,_)pair in the same complexity as the original find method (in O(1) on average)?

Comment: I think your best chance would be to use `unordered_map` instead of `unordered_set`?

Comment: It's a good solution for my problem and generally. But it has to be a way to make this in unordered_set

Comment: The core problem is that `std::unordered_set` is implemented as a close addressing hash table, therefore the elements are sorted in no particular order but organized into buckets depending on their hash values. It guarantees that individual elements can be accessed by their key, using the given hash function object, and time complexity is O(1) in average case. If you can not access directly the bucket were the element should be inserted following its hash value (it seems you can not do this), there is no way to get a find operation that guarantees a time complexity better than O(N).